# Rails - Writing a Where Query With an Or Clause

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having trouble figuring out how to combine to queries into one with my Rails 5 app (mySQL).  I want `@activities` to return the Activity records that meet the criteria for Query 1 or 2.

Can someone please help me?  Thank you!

Query 1

```
@activities = Activity.where(owner_id: current_user.friend_ids, owner_type: "User")
```

Query 2

```
@activities = Activity.where(recipient_id: current_user.id)
```

Comment: You should use OR condition in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ............

```
@activities =  Activity.where("(owner_id in = ? and owner_type = ?) or recipent_id = ?", current_user.friend_ids,"User",current_user.id )
```

**For Rails 5** :

```
@activities =  Activity.where(owner_id: current_user.friend_ids, owner_type: "User").or(Activity.where(recipient_id: current_user.id))
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below

```
@activities =  Activity.where("(owner_id in = ? and owner_type = ?) or recipent_id = ?", current_user.friend_ids,"User",current_user.id )
```

or

```
@activities =  Activity.where(owner_id: current_user.friend_ids, owner_type: "User").or(Activity.where(recipient_id: current_user.id))
```

Answer (score 3):

using AREL is a great way to get OR or AND queries going, its a more programatic way of getting the SQL queries you want as you can build them up and meta program them in easily, and it avoids using direct SQL strings which can get too big and complex and unreadable, but here is a snippet for your code to get you going:

```
table = Activity.arel_table
query = arel_table['owner_id'].in(current_user.friend_ids).and(arel_table['owner_type'].eq("User"))
query = query.or(arel_table['recipient_id'].eq(current_user.id))
@activities = Activity.where(query)
```

I strongly recommend looking up more about using AREL, here are some pages to see more:

[definitive guide to arel](http://jpospisil.com/2014/06/16/the-definitive-guide-to-arel-the-sql-manager-for-ruby.html)
[using arel to compose sql queries](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-arel-to-compose-sql-queries)

#### EDIT

For some reason I decided to completely ignore the fact that you are runnin rails 5, in which case Akshay's answer / Chakreshwar Sharma's second answer is definately the way to go.

However I still recommend learning about and getting to grips with AREL is it can really help out in a lot of other cases where you might have more complex queries to write!

Comment: I personally choose to use Arel rather than raw sql in ActiveRecord because if you use Arel you can rely on it to build the correct syntax for the db you are using. Raw sql is something that has to be maintained or changed if you decide to move to a different database.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this way:

```
# load all ids for owner
activity_ids_by_owner = Activity.where(owner_id: current_user.friend_ids, owner_type: "User").pluck(:id)
# load all ids for recipient
activity_ids_by_recipient = Activity.where(recipient_id: current_user.id).pluck(:id)

# load all activities for founded ids
Activity.where(id: activity_ids_by_owner | activity_ids_by_recipient)
```